# How to solve the recurrence $T(n) = T(n/3) + T(2n/3)$?

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

It's not solvable by Master Theorem and I couldn't find any solution on the web. I am not familiar with generating functions so it would be nice if you can post a solution without them.

I found the top answer here a little helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25717513/solving-the-recurrence-tn-tn-3-t2n-3-n2 Based on this answer I have tried this,

We have that,

> T(n) = T(n / 3) + T(2n / 3)

Consider this other recurrence:

> S(n) = S(2n / 3) + S(2n / 3) = 2S(2n / 3)

Since T(n) is increasing and T(n) ≤ S(n), any upper bound for S(n) should also be an upper-bound for T(n).

Using the Master Theorem on S(n), we have that a = 2, b = 3/2, and c = 0. Since logb a = log3/2 2 = 1.709511291... < c, the Master Theorem says that this will solve to O(n^1.70). Since S(n) = O(n^1.70), we also know that T(n) = O(n^1.70). Is this method correct?

EDIT: I also found this https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/22809/recurrence-of-tn-tn-3-t2n-3 but couldn't proceed even with the hint.

Comment: What are the initial values? What happens when n isn't a multiple of 3?

Comment: @Sophie We can assume T(a) = Theta(1) for any constant a.

Comment: $T(n)=n+k$ is a trivial solution of $T(n)=T(n/3)+T(2n/3)$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I want to find an upper bound for this recurrence (BigO). Sorry if that wasn't clear from the question.

Comment: @StupidMan: then $T(n)=O(n)$ is a trivial upper bound.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Can you please show some work. How did you arrive at that result and what's wrong with my attempt? Thanks.

Comment: If $T(a+b)=T(a)+T(b)$ and $T$ is continuous then $T$ is linear.